# How to cure regular syslog error?

Tags: syslog, sendmail

I'm getting regular errors in my syslog (they're occurring exactly every 10 minutes, to the second):

```
Feb 22 13:01:24 computer sm-mta[5747]: q1MBVO6B003778: SYSERR(root): hash map "Alias0": missing map file /etc/mail/aliases.db: No such file or directory
```

I don't know how to interpret these errors, but am I right in guessing that the `sm-mta[5747]`   part of of the error is the application name and process ID? If so, this would seem odd to me as I do not have sm-mta installed and System Monitor does not have a process ID with that number. I'm probably being stupid as usual!

How can I find out what's causing these errors and stop them from occuring, please?

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! If Oli's answer answered your question you can just check the checkmark by his answer, that marks it solved, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I read `sm-mta` as `sendmail` MTA (Message transfer agent). That seems to make sense based on the error message.

`sendmail` is a program that relays email messages around, either letting applications send email through it, or accepting email and routing it towards mailboxes.

So a couple of things:

- **You've got `sendmail` installed!** It's a *horrible* application so unless you've got a good reason for it to be installed, I suggest you nuke it.

  ```
  sudo apt-get remove sendmail
  ```

  If this moans about wanting to remove other applications which are dependent on the `sendmail` package, weigh it up. If those applications just need something to provide `default-mta` or `mail-transport-agent`, consider using `postfix` which provides those roles.
- If you need a local MTA (to handle email), I suggest `postfix`. Nice, fairly simple and very capable.

  ```
  sudo apt-get install postfix
  ```
- If you *need* `sendmail` (ie something has a hard dependency on it that you can't replace), then you want to look at fixing this specific error. Something like this might work:

  ```
  makemap hash /etc/mail/aliases.db < /etc/mail/aliases
  ```

Comment: Thanks Oli, but I had already nuked sendmail (by removing it in Synaptic) which is another reason why this error is baffling me. (I wish I'd never installed the blasted software but a program I thought I needed insisted on installing sendmail as well. I've since nuked both.) I don't need postfix either and ideally I'd like to track down the culprit that's causing this error and nuke that too, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

Bah!  Although I had removed sendmail I had not restarted my computer. I didn't realise that some vestiges of the program would still run after Synaptic had uninstalled it! Checking now, after a restart, I'm not getting those errors any more. Sorry to have troubled everyone! (Should I delete this question? And if so, how?)